# jQuery each number

Tags: jquery, each

I have a idea to make table like this

```
 1. something1
 2. something2
 3. something3
```

I have made a table:

```
<table>
   <tr><td id="rb">...
   <tr><td id="rb">...
</table>
```

so in #rb is this sequence number starting from 1.

I have this jQuery code but it doesn't work. Can you pls help :)

```
            $('tr').each(function(index) 
            {
                  $('#rb').append(index);
             });
```

It just make

```
       012345
```

in the first #rb

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why use a table for an ordered list? There's an element for that.

Comment: `id` must be unique, better use a `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not give same id to more than one element within same HTML document. You can do the same using `class="rb"` instead.

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
   $(this).find('.rb').append(index);
});
```

Comment: Wohoou,, thnak you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an `#id` multiple times.

Instead you can use either a class of `.rb` like:

```
$('tr').each(function(index){
   $(this).children('.rb')append(index+1);
});
```

or an approach like this just by selecting the children of each `tr` (might not work depending on your HTML structure):

```
$('tr').each(function(index) { //index will start at 0
   $(this).children('td').append(index+1); //$(this) is the tr, its child element of td is selected, then the index is appended
});
```

Comment: The OP is obviously trying to implement filtering with the `rb`

Comment: @Starx it's not *that* obvious to me, but I'll add that to my answer, you are right